# NSFW comic strip of two demon girlfriends

Tags: story-identification, comics, demons

I am looking for a comic strip of two demon girlfriends. It was only one or two pages at most, and it went basically: the two were making out, and one of them degrades the other one. At this, the other one starts crying, and the first one freaks out, starting to apologise.

Comment: What sort of art style? Do you read other webcomics which might share a host? Was there a large archive of strips? How often did strips come out? How explicit was it? By "degrade", do you mean BDSM? Physical damage? Name-calling?

Comment: I just realized I may have misread that. Web or paper comic? If the latter, graphic novel or individual issues? A feature in a magazine like *Playboy* or *Analog SF&F*?

Comment: My first instinct was that this was an Oglaf comic, but I couldn't find it in a cursory scan of the site.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan it's not the oglaf comic; that's not how the scene plays out.

Comment: Hey guys! First of all, I have not read any other comics by the host, and sadly I don't know who drew it either :/ It wasn't that explicit, and by degrade I mean verbally only, saying stuff like "Look at you, you're so pathetic". I just found it on some site lol. I don't think it was an Oglaf comic, though the art styles were kinda similar I think? It was rather cartoonish.

Answer (score 1):

A story arc from Fuchsia and Criminy, perhaps? I don’t recognize a particular episode (almost 20 years in archive)... But two devil girls, sometimes really ‘friendly’, sometimes not, seemed about right. I’ll defer to the original poster after he or she examines the example:

https://www.sinfest.net/view.php?date=2009-01-11

Note that the character artwork has changed over 20 years.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches a bit more? Do you know the story arc or rough time period for what the OP is looking for at least?

Comment: Hello! The demons in the artwork I am looking for were looking rather alternative punk, so I don't think this is what I'm looking for, unfortunately. But thank you for your input! Now I do remember that one of them had a dull blue/purple color scheme, and I think that the other one had a pink color scheme? But yeah, they definitely looked pretty punk. Oh, and also, I think that the art style of the comic I'm searching was more detailed than the one in your example.

Comment: On the example, click on archive. The artwork  has changed over the years. Check out the first, last and a couple of other years. See if any are closer to what you remember.